# Do variable declarations get optimized in the C# compiler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mono, monodevelop

Does the C# compiler, either in visual studio or monodevelop, optimize variable declarations with regard to memory?

For instance, in example 1, does C# create a new 4 bytes of memory in every single for loop iteration? In example 2, a new 4 bytes memory for each function call? Example 3, a new 4 bytes memory for each class?

Does C# optimize all 3 examples to where only one int is used for memory purposes?

Three examples: 1: First one inside the for loop:

```
void testfunction(){
   for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
      int x = j*2;
      //x used for a lot of stuff
   }
}
```

2: Outside the for loop:

```
void testfunction(){
   int x=0;
   for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
      x = j*2;
      //x used for a lot of stuff
   }
}
```

3: Outside the function and the for loop:

```
int x=0;
void testfunction(){
   for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
      x=j*2;
      //x used for a lot of stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: These variables take no memory at all.  Both the x and the j variable will be stored in a CPU register.  So yes, it is very heavily optimized.  Not by the C# compiler, it is done by the jitter.  You cannot see this from the IL at Mitch suggests, you have to look at the optimized machine code.  Something else you'll see is that the x variable is completely eliminated.  It isn't used for anything.

Comment: It should be noted that example 3 is not thread-safe and that method should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @cmbasnett - this is not a C question.  x is a private member of a class, there's nothing inherently thread-unsafe about it.

Comment: Right, sorry.  If `testfunction` was public and its containing object was publicly accessible, this would be unsafe, but you're right, the examples are not inherently thread-unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the nitty gritty in regards to C#, but rules of C still apply, which I will explain below.

### Method 1

```
void testfunction(){
   for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
      int x = j*2;
      //x used for a lot of stuff
   }
}
```

The stack reference to `x` is reassigned every iteration.  This is an extremely fast operation and you would probably never have any appreciable slowdown because of this.

### Method 2

```
void testfunction(){
   int x=0;
   for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
      x = j*2;
      //x used for a lot of stuff
   }
}
```

This is the most correct and fastest method.  The `x` stack reference is only assigned once and is used throughout the duration of the function.

### Method 3

```
int x=0;
void testfunction(){
   for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
      x=j*2;
      //x used for a lot of stuff
   }
}
```

This method is not thread-safe if `testfunction` is public, as two threads could be running `testfunction` at the same time and thrasing the values of `x` for each other.  Do *not* do this, as there is no speed, memory or readability gain.

Comment: Method 2: x is assigned 10k times, since it's inside the loop. Also, there is no difference whatsoever between Method 1 and 2 in your code (once the code has been jitted to machine code at runtime).